# Selenium NoSuchElement occurs due to popup although locator is correct

Tags: selenium-webdriver, popup, alert, nosuchelementexception

I want to be able to click the ok button as shown in the below image.

popup box

[image: 1]

The ok button can actually be directly located with the By.id("_popup_path_sol_ok"); as this is unique to the page. However i receive a NoSuchElementException.

I have checked thoroughly there is no frame, i tried getwindowhandles but there is only one handle.
I have tried multiple xpath locators but findelement does not locate the ok button in the popup even though the xpath locates it on the DOM.

The driver.switchTo.alert().accept() as well does not work, mostly it does not consider this element to be a popup.
Last but not the least, i tried robot class and pressed ESC and Enter but even that does not work.

I really need to find a way out to handle this popup.

Comment: That looks like it would take some time to appear on a page and isn't loaded initially. Have you tried adding an explicit wait to your code?

Comment: Can you add html source of the page her so that its easier to understand? Also, if you can, please add the code snippet as well which you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing go with the CssSelector.put the wait for the appear to popup and use the below code. here you will get all the elements from the page and find the unique element from the popup and put the IF condition to validate your Scenario.
 AllElement=driver.findelements(By.cssSelector("*"));

systm.out.println("All the Element from the Page"+AllElement);

if(AllElement.contains("Unique element from the Popup")
{
perform your action
}
else
{
}